# Xcode + AWS Integration Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services

I have a very simple Xcode project that I started and am now trying to integrate the Amazon Web Service (AWS) SDK into my project. I followed the instructions posted on their [instruction page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#) and everything looks good EXCEPT that I've got the following output...

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLDictionaryParser in:
    /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ryanmord/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FocalApplication-brblhwteebzxgycscfnynvdcptjx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-XMLDictionary.a(XMLDictionary.o)
    /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ryanmord/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.2/third-party/XMLDictionary.framework/XMLDictionary(XMLDictionary.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XMLDictionaryParser in:
    /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ryanmord/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FocalApplication-brblhwteebzxgycscfnynvdcptjx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-XMLDictionary.a(XMLDictionary.o)
    /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ryanmord/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.2/third-party/XMLDictionary.framework/XMLDictionary(XMLDictionary.o)
ld: 5771 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the very end of the output, but as the 2nd to last line says, I've got 5771 other duplicate symbols worth of output as well. Im not sure if this is related to the "clang error" that Im getting, but regardless this is a roadblock for me that I can't figure out. I've seen recommendations from duplicate libraries, to changing the valid architectures in my project, but I'm not sure what will break my app and what won't. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS using both the frameworks and CocoaPods? You cannot import the SDK twice, and that is why you are getting duplicate symbols errors. You need to pick one of them and remove the other one to remove the errors.

Comment: I've got my application AND a Pods project in my Xcode project structure. I assume this means Im using both? My project has all the frameworks. Is this as simple as removing all the linked libraries from my application?

Comment: That was it. I removed all frameworks from my application leaving ONLY the pods project and its contents. Thanks for your help!